# Could not compile used unit 'SHDocVw.pas' (Delphi) Active X

Tags: delphi, activex, browser, upgrade

I'm upgrading a application from Delphi 6 to Delphi XE.  I am using a TWebBrowser but for some reason Delphi refuses to recognize TWebBrowser as a type and also keeps adding in ShDocVw to the uses clause.  It then throws the error

```
Could not compile used unit 'SHDocVw.pas'
```

I'm not quite sure why it adds this.  Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: It is the unit where TWebBrowser lives, that's why the IDE is adding it to the uses clause. Maybe you have imported the Microsoft Internet Controls for the D6 project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just copying the SHDocVw_TBL.pas from where it was in the Delphi XE source and pasting it in my code folder.  I then renamed it SHDocVw, and everything works fine.  Apparently Delphi wasn't smart enough to realize that SHDocVw_TBL was the same thing.

Comment: How could Delphi be "smart enough to realize that SHDocVw_TBL was the same thing"? It isn't the same thing! One compiles and the other doesn't - a clear different. One came from Delphi 6 and was not Unicode Delphi aware, and the new one is suitable for Unicode Delphi. They really are different, and there's no way yet for computer programs to read the minds of their users - if there was then I guess there would be no use for Stack Overflow!!

Comment: @Radu - It's the same thing.. <g>